# Changing nickname of bot with a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to make changes to my bot's name with a command like `!Changenick nick` - by 'nick' I mean the new bot's name. Could you guys help me? I just want bot to change username when someone writes `!Changenick` for example:

`!changenick Freshname`

*bot changes his own name to Freshname*

Comment: Have you looked through the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) at all? What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change a users nickname you need a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) obj. You can apply this to the bot by searching the guild's member prop for the bots id. The following line will allow you to change the bot's username given a [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) obj.

`message.guild.me.setNickname('NICKNAME');` *updated based on suggestion from @slothiful*

If you need further assistance with how to create the entire command, reference https://discordjs.guide/ and https://discord.js.org/#/docs/

**Update 1**: I am having a hard time understanding your desired implementation with the examples you have provided.

Let's assume you want a command something like this: `!changenick <@user> <nickname>`

In this case, I would reference [this](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#implementation). It explains how you can parse mentions. On to the actual question of changing the nickname, you can change the nickname of any user 
 (you will get this user via the mention) by using `message.guild.members.find(user => user.id === mentionUser.id).setNickname('NICKNAME')`

**Update 2:** I now see what you were getting at. My apologies. You do not need to restart the bot to allow the nickname to update. I have tested it.

The below code changes the bots nickname every 10 seconds.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

Client.on('ready', () => {
    let value = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
        Client.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === 'GUILD_ID').me.setNickname(value++);
    }, 10000);
});

Client.login('TOKEN');
```

The important bit is
`Client.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === 'GUILD_ID').me.setNickname('NICKNAME');`

**Edit:** If this answers your question, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Use `message.guild.me` instead of finding the client (which also returns a promise).